# What data format is this and how can I convert it to XML?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, format, converters

after writing a python script to request some data from a server, I get the response in following structure:

```
{
    'E_AXIS_DATA': {
        'item': [
            {
                'AXIS': '000',
                'SET': {
                    'item': [
                        {
                            'TUPLE_ORDINAL': '000000',
                            'CHANM': '0002',
                            'CAPTION': 'ECF',
                            'CHAVL': '0002',
                            'CHAVL_EXT': None,
                            'TLEVEL': '00',
                            'DRILLSTATE': None,
                            'ATTRIBUTES': None
                        },
                        {...
```

Apparently its not JSON.
After running following command:

```
results = client.service.RRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA("/server") 
df = pd.read_json(results)
```

i get the output meaning that the format is not being accepted as JSON;

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'zeep.objects.RRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATAResponse'>
```

Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: This is JSON format. In this [article](https://datatofish.com/export-pandas-dataframe-json/) you could know how to export it to pandas

Comment: It looks like JSON from what you've shown us. I suspect the error message is saying that it can't find it.

Comment: I get following error log when I try to output the results in a *.json file:

TypeError: Object of type 'RRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATAResponse' is not JSON serializable

Comment: Can I know how did you fetch data?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has DataFrame.read_json() method that can do the trick

```py
import pandas as pd

json_string = '{"content": "a string containing some JSON...." ... etc... }'
df = pd.load_json(json_string)

# Now you can do whatever you like with your dataframe
```